# Period of $i\mapsto S_0\,x^i\bmod P$

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let $P$ be a given polynomial of degree $n$ with coefficients in a finite field.
Let $S_0$ be a given polynomial of degree less than $n$ with coefficients in that field.

How do we derive the (smallest) period of $i\mapsto S_i=S_0\,x^i\bmod P$ ?

---

My initial motivation/exploration was with the Boolean field, where $S_i$ is the state of a Galois LFSR with polynomial $P$ and initial state $S_0$, in a cryptographic [context](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59861/555). I see that

- if $S_0=0$, period is 1
- if $P$ is irreducible and $S_0\ne0$ then

  - $S_0$ is coprime with $P$;
  - thus the period is the smallest $i$ with $x^i-1$ a multiple of $P$;
  - restricting to the Boolean case in the next bullet points, the period divides $2^n-1$, and is exactly that for primitive $P$;
  - we can experimentally find the period by factoring $2^n-1$ and pulling out those factors $u_j$ leaving $x^{(2^n-1)/(\prod u_j)}-1$ a multiple of $P$, with that condition testable with $O(n^3)$ time and $O(n)$ memory; but I wonder if there's a more direct method.
- otherwise

  - we can factor $P$ into $\prod P_i$ with $P_i$ primitive of order $n_i$;
  - the period divides $\prod(2^{n_i}-1)$, but I'm moving out of my comfort zone.

My math background is engineering+self-taught, and I'm struggling in particular about

1. how $\gcd(P,S_0)$ can be used to predict how the period varies with $S_0$;
2. what's the effect of squares in the factorization of $P$;
3. how we can obtain the factorization of $P$ better than by trial division with irreducible polynomials (or delegating to [Wolfram's Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%201%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E11%2Bx%5E13%2Bx%5E16%2Bx%5E18%2Bx%5E20%2Bx%5E24%2Bx%5E25%2Bx%5E26%2Bx%5E27%2Bx%5E28%2Bx%5E29%2Bx%5E31%2Bx%5E33%2Bx%5E34%2Bx%5E35%2Bx%5E36%2Bx%5E37%2Bx%5E40%2Bx%5E41%2Bx%5E44%2Bx%5E46%2Bx%5E47%2Bx%5E50%2Bx%5E51%2Bx%5E52%2Bx%5E54%2Bx%5E55%2Bx%5E56%2Bx%5E57%2Bx%5E60%2Bx%5E63%2Bx%5E64%20modulo%202));
4. how things generalize for a finite field other than Booleans.